# LogicException: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

After logout  i want redirect to index page , but i getting an error in FOSUserBundle

In SecurityController.php

```
 <?php
      namespace ispg\Bundle\ChatBundle\Controller;
      namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

      use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
      use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
      use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
      use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

 class SecurityController extends ContainerAware
 {
     public function loginAction()
     {        
          $request = $this->container->get('request');
          /* @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
          $session = $request->getSession();
          /* @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session */
          $network = $request->get("network");

          // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
          if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
             $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
          } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
             $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
             $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
          } else {
             $error = '';
          }

          if ($error) {
              // TODO: this is a potential security risk (see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9523)
              $error = $error->getMessage();
          }

          // last username entered by the user
          $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME);

          //create the select tag for network selection
          require 'mnoNetworks.php';
          $selectHtml = "<select id=\"networks\">
                         <option value=\"\"> -- Select -- </option>";

          foreach($networks as $network){
             $selectHtml .= "<option value=\"".$network."\">".$network."</option>";
          }
          $selectHtml .="</select>";

          return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'), array(
               'last_username' => $lastUsername,
               'error'         => $error,
               'network'        => $network,
               'networkSelector' => $selectHtml
           ));
      }

      public function checkAction()
      {
           throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
      }

      public function logoutAction()
      {
           $bundle2 = new \ispg\Bundle\ChatBundle\Controller\DefaultController();
           $bundle2->setContainer($this->container);
           $returned_data = $bundle2->san();
       }
 }
```

After logoutAction  session  I want to redirect to index page
how to redirect to it .

Is any one can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jaitsu is right, it's just that your Controller extends ContainerAware but not Controller class that provides shortcuts for basic controller actions...

```
return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('name_of_route'));
```

Comment: its showing error :           Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Controller\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse' not found in /var/www/html/pan.ispghosting.com/phpver3/mno/vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php on line 77

Answer (score 3):

You need to call redirect inside your `logoutAction()`...

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('name_of_route'));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::redirect() in